# Re-assigning contents of title column in SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, list, column

I have a SharePoint list with multiple columns and almost 5000 entries. I would like to change the information in the 'title' column to 'Choice' instead of 'Single line of text' From what I have been reading, it is a bad idea to mess with the title column so instead I would simply like to move the contents of the title column to a different column and hide the title column.

Is there a way to do this with so many entries without copying and pasting 500 times? Or another way to get around the information being in the restricted title column?

Comment: You can write a CSOM code to copy the title information to a new column within the same list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the datasheet view of your list. Here you easy copy paste a whole column to another column. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ko_6rpmVuD8) is an example of how the datasheet view works: